# Regex to choose one random occurence of a keyword between a { and } sign

Tags: regex

My text example:

> {this is a text example and this is my KEYWORD, but my KEYWORD is in this text multiple times and I only want one of my KEYWORD replaced, but it should be chosen randomly every time}

So out of the three keywords I only want one replaced, chosen randomly. Sometimes my keyword appears more than three times, sometimes only once.
Is this possible with RegEx?

Comment: Regex hath no random generator.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible only with regex.

You could, however, use regex to find all of the keywords, generate a random number, and use that number to replace one occurance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser. That would be great. How do I do that? Can you help me? Thanks&all the best, Marton

Comment: You haven't even said what language your code is in, so we can't really provide specifics :)

Comment: or just generate the random word through your programming language into the regex

Answer (score 0):

## Description

you didn't select a language, so in the example here I've used powershell. Each time it runs punctuation marks are removed and the string is broken into words. Then a word is selected at random.

## Disclaimer

There may be some words which require punctuation marks such a single quote, aka apostrophes at the end of a plural possessive noun, or hyphenated names.... That being said you'd have to structure the punctuation mark replacement regex around your string

## Example

```
clear

$String = "This lazy brown dog, jumped over the red fox."

# strip out punctuation marks
$String = $String -replace "[^\w\s\d]", ""

# split the string into an array
[array]$ArrayOfWords = $String -split " "

# select a random word from the array
$ArrayOfWords | Get-Random
```